# Logic Pro X Gate Stutter

Tags: production, logic-pro, effects

Is there an easier way to use create a stutter effect in Logic for something like a riser or anything else WITHOUT side-chaining to the noise gate plugin? I've only seen tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UwbyxBQMXE&t=189s). By the way, I know that they're NOT using Logic Pro X in the video. They made their gated effect so easy and it seems like you have to do way more work in Logic to get the same thing done.

Answer (score 1):

Tremolo?

[image: Tremolo in logic.]

A tremolo plugin may be exactly what you need. It's under the modulation plugins and creates a stuttery type effect. The higher the depth the higher the on/off jumps in level will be.

You may be able to use automation with this to get the "speed up" stutter effect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, it doesn't really approximate a gating plugin because it's never really off for any responsible amount of time. Thank you though.